# NDSolve with a 0/0 error

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, singularity

I am trying to solve this set of coupled first order differential equations.  The $\phi'$ term gives a 0/0 error for when $\epsilon=0$. When I enter:

```
NDSolve[{ϕ'[ϵ] == -1/ϵ^2 ((1 + (8 c ϕ[ϵ])/αm[M]) (Mhat[ϵ] + 
   c αm[M]^3 ϵ^3 ghat[ϕ[ϵ]/αm[M]]))/(
1 - ((16 c)/αm[M]) (Mhat[ϵ]/ϵ)), 
  Mhat'[ϵ] == αm[M]^3 ϵ^2 (((ϕ[ϵ]/αm[M])^2 - 1)^(3/2) + 3 c fhat[ϕ[ϵ]/αm[M]]), 
 Mhat[0] == 0, ϕ[0] == 1, ϕ'[0] == 0}, {Mhat, ϕ}, {ϵ, 0, 1}]
```

Where:

```
ghat[y_] := 3 ArcSinh[Sqrt[y^2 - 1]] + y (2 y^2 - 5) Sqrt[y^2 - 1]
fhat[y_] := y (2 y^2 - 1) Sqrt[y^2 - 1] - ArcSinh[Sqrt[y^2 - 1]]
```

and $\alpha m[M]$ is just a constant.

I get

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at \[Epsilon] == 0.`.
```

I have tried adding the condition $\phi'[0]==0$, but then I get:

```
NDSolve::icordinit: The initial values for all the dependent variables are not explicitly specified. 
NDSolve will attempt to find consistent initial conditions for all the variables.
NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (3) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables (2).
```

I have also tried replacing the $\phi'$ expression with a piecewise function that is the same as the above expression for $\phi'$ except that it is set to zero at $\epsilon=0$.  This gives me a solution that is only valid at $\epsilon=0$.

I know this can be solved numerically, I just can't figure out how to get mathematica to do it.

Comment: There are several undefined functions.  Can't really help beyond Bill's observation that epsilon = 0 is a singular point.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same 1/0 type error when I rearrange both sides to remove the explicit division by zero terms.  I have edited the above description to include the undefined terms.

Comment: I don't think multiplying by epsilon will work because the first thing `NDSolve` does is to solve for the derivatives.  Multiplying both sides of an equation won't change that.  We need your complete code, because dealing with singular points is tricky.

Comment: I agree that these equations can be solved, but not without values for `c` and `αm[M]`.  Please provide.

Answer (score 2):

This system of equations can be solved as follows.  For convenience, define

```
eq1 = ϕ'[ϵ] == -1/ϵ^2 ((1 + (8 c ϕ[ϵ])/αm[M]) (Mhat[ϵ] + c αm[M]^3 ϵ^3 ghat[ϕ[ϵ]
    /αm[M]]))/(1 - ((16 c)/αm[M]) (Mhat[ϵ]/ϵ));
eq2 = Mhat'[ϵ] == αm[M]^3 ϵ^2 (((ϕ[ϵ]/αm[M])^2 - 1)^(3/2) + 3 c fhat[ϕ[ϵ]/αm[M]]);
```

Because the system of equations is singular at `ϵ = 0`, expand the right side of `eq2` there.

```
Normal@Series[Last[eq2], {ϵ, 0, 2}] /. ϕ[0] -> 1
(* ϵ^2 αm[M]^3 (((1 - αm[M]^2)/αm[M]^2)^(3/2) + 3 c (-ArcSinh[Sqrt[-1 + 1/αm[M]^2]] + 
   ((-1 + 2/αm[M]^2) Sqrt[(1 - αm[M]^2)/αm[M]^2])/αm[M])) *)
```

It follows that `MHat` varies as `ϵ^3` near `ϵ = 0`, so make the substitution, `Mhat[ϵ] -> ϵ^3 Nhat[ϵ]` and expand the right side of `eq1`.

```
Normal@Series[Last[eq1 /. Mhat[ϵ] -> ϵ^3 Nhat[ϵ]], {ϵ, 0, 1}] /. ϕ[0] -> 1
(* -ϵ (1 + (8 c)/αm[M]) (Nhat[0] + c αm[M]^3 (3 ArcSinh[Sqrt[-1 + 1/αm[M]^2]] + 
   ((-5 + 2/αm[M]^2) Sqrt[(1 - αm[M]^2)/αm[M]^2])/αm[M])) *)
```

which now is well behaved and also consistent with the OP's desire that `ϕ'[0] == 0`.  So, make the `Nhat` substitution into the two equations.

```
eq1r = Simplify[eq1 /. Mhat[ϵ] -> ϵ^3 Nhat[ϵ]]
(* ϕ'[ϵ] == 1/(16 c ϵ^2 Nhat[ϵ] - αm[M]) ϵ (αm[M] + 8 c ϕ[ϵ]) (Nhat[ϵ] + 
   c (3 ArcSinh[Sqrt[-1 + ϕ[ϵ]^2/αm[M]^2]] αm[M]^3 - 5 αm[M]^2 ϕ[ϵ] 
   Sqrt[-1 + ϕ[ϵ]^2/αm[M]^2] + 2 ϕ[ϵ]^3 Sqrt[-1 + ϕ[ϵ]^2/αm[M]^2])) *)

eq2r = Simplify[((#/ϵ^2) & /@ eq2) /. Mhat -> Function[{ϵ}, ϵ^3 Nhat[ϵ]]]
(* 3 Nhat[ϵ] + 3 c ArcSinh[Sqrt[-1 + ϕ[ϵ]^2/αm[M]^2]] αm[M]^3 + 
   3 c ϕ[ϵ] (αm[M]^2 - 2 ϕ[ϵ]^2) Sqrt[-1 + ϕ[ϵ]^2/αm[M]^2] + 
   ϵ Nhat'[ϵ] == αm[M]^3 (-1 + ϕ[ϵ]^2/αm[M]^2)^(3/2) *)
```

In order that `eq2r` be well behaved at `ϵ = 0`, the boundary condition `Nhat[0]` must be chosen such that `eq2r` reduces to `0 == 0` there.

```
Nhat0 = Nhat[0] /. Flatten@Solve[eq2r /. ϵ -> 0 /. ϕ[0] -> 1, Nhat[0]]
(* 1/3 (6 c Sqrt[-1 + 1/αm[M]^2] + Sqrt[-1 + 1/αm[M]^2] αm[M] - 
   3 c Sqrt[-1 + 1/αm[M]^2] αm[M]^2 - 3 c ArcSinh[Sqrt[-1 + 1/αm[M]^2]] αm[M]^3 - 
   Sqrt[-1 + 1/αm[M]^2] αm[M]^3) *)
```

With these transformations the ODEs can be solved by

```
ϵ0 = 10^-6;
s = NDSolveValue[{eq1r, eq2r, ϕ[ϵ0] == 1, Nhat[ϵ0] == Nhat0} /. {c -> 1, αm[M] -> 1/6}, 
    {ϕ[ϵ], Nhat[ϵ]}, {ϵ, ϵ0, 1}];
Plot[First@s, {ϵ, ϵ0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {ϵ, ϕ}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
Plot[ϵ^3 Last@s, {ϵ, ϵ0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {ϵ, Mhat}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

[image]

In the absence of definitions in the Question for the two constants, I chose `c = 1` arbitrarily, and `αm[M]` slightly smaller than `ϕ[1]`, so that `-1 + ϕ[ϵ]^2/αm[M]^2 > 0`.